# Centering content vertically in list which is displayed as table rows

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I am creating vertical page navigation. I know exact height (300px) and that there will be 5 items (all of them may be of different sizes, but none of them will exceed 60px of height).

What I want to achieve is to display all the items centered vertically in their table row, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6sp5n7xg/.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5<br />Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #EEE;
}

ul {
    display: table;
}

ul li {
    display: table-row;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Horizontally it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vq9mt02h/1/, but I want it also to be vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Here a working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/6sp5n7xg/1/)  that starts from your code, only slightly modified. You must wrap each cell content in a `span` and set it `display:table-cell;`, moving to this selector also properties about `height` and `vertical-align` (I added also a red border to highlight middle alignement). So, here the modified code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><span>Item 1</span></li>
        <li><span>Item 2</span></li>
        <li><span>Item 3</span></li>
        <li><span>Item 4</span></li>
        <li><span>Item 5<br />Item 6</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    display: table-row;
}

ul li span {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 60px;
    border:solid 1px red;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the love of everything sacred don't abuse tables for this. Flexbox is your saviour, both for the menu layout itself, and for the perfect bidirectional centering. Consider the following sample:

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
ul, li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
li {
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    height: 60px;
    width:120px;
    border:1px dotted black;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5<br />Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Change `flex-direction` on the `ul` to `row` to have the same layout horizontally.

Only need to [forget support for IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), but since that's 3 major versions gone by now that's generally considered fine for most sites.